# the callback result of bootstrapvalidator remote is a json

Tags: javascript, json, validation

i'm using bootstrapValidator with type of remote,it seem that the callback from backend should be a boolean value ,but my backend callback is a json ,how can i use the validator to read a boolean value from the result of json? thx!

following is the code of validate:

```
remote: {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'account/validator',
    message: 'username is not valid',
    delay: 2000
}
```

following is the json:

```
{"data":true}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

```
var response = '{"data":true}';
```

... simply use:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response).data; // true
```

Comment: thx for asking,i've using HttpServletResponse solved this problem ,backend java code:

json="{valid:true} ";
new HttpServletResponse().getWriter().print(json);


and the json was i needed.

Comment: Sweet, I'm glad you got your answer! Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it helped you :)